# Maximal numerical simplification of a symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

When I enter this code in Mathematica

```
t^3 + 6898033663572324079/6917529027641081856 // N
```

it simplifies expression into `0.997182 + t^3`.

How do I achieve the same behavior in MATLAB? Note that the `t` is a symbolic variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`vpa`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html):

```
syms t
outExact = t^3 + 6898033663572324079/6917529027641081856
outFloat = vpa(outExact)
```

---

```
outExact =

t^3 + 8981814666109797/9007199254740992


outFloat =

t^3 + 0.99718174452310093247575650821091
```

---

optional you can set the number of digits with e.g. `digits(5)` to get:

```
outFloat =

t^3 + 0.99718
```

or `outFloat = vpa(outExact,5)` which has the same effect.

---

The scientific notation is not trivial, here is a **non-generic** solution as a starting point:

```
f(t) = t^3 + 6898033663572324079/6917529027641081856
remain = f(0)
f(t) = f(t) - remain
sprintf('%s + %1.3e',char(f(t)),double(remain))
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to show the result in a scientific notation?
I mean `t^3 + 9.9718e-1`.

Comment: @NoMan That would't be trivial. You need to create your own output string e.g. using `sprintf`.

Comment: @NoMan I added a solution for the scientific notation, but it is non-generic. But if its really important to you, you can use it as a starting point.